# The QML MouseArea property doesn't handle the "target"

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qqmlcomponent, mousearea

We have a project in which there are some components and one of them is named `Racket.qml` which is as below:

```
import QtQuick 2.9

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 15; height: 65
    property int oldY: y
    property bool yUwards: false
    property bool yDwards: false

    onYChanged: {
        if(y > oldY)  yDwards = true
        else if (y < oldY)  yUwards = true
        oldY = y
    }

    Item {
        x: root.x - 50
        y: root.y - 50
        width: 100
        height: 200

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: root
            focus: true
            hoverEnabled: true
            pressAndHoldInterval: 0
            drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
            drag.minimumY: table.y
            drag.maximumY: table.height - height - 10
        }
    }
}
```

I've used that component in `main.qml` this way:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Window {
    id: window
    title: qsTr("Test")
    color: "gray"

    Rectangle {
        id: table
        width: window.width / 1.15; height: window.height / 1.15
        x: window.x + 100; y: 10;

        Racket {
            id: blackRacket
            anchors.left: table.left
            anchors.leftMargin: width * 2
            y: height
            color: "black"
        }
        Racket {
            id: redRacket
            anchors.right: table.right
            anchors.rightMargin: width * 2
            y: height
            color: "red"
        }
      ...
```

My purpose was just to widen the area of the Rackets but now when I run the program I can't drag the rackets!

What can the problem be please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging, add a transparent `Rectangle` with a colored border to the `MouseArea`.

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    drag.target: root
    focus: true
    hoverEnabled: true
    pressAndHoldInterval: 0
    drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
    drag.minimumY: table.y
    drag.maximumY: table.height - height - 10
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: 'transparent'
        border.color: 'black'
    }
}
```

You will see that the `MouseArea` is wrongly placed. That is, as your `Item`'s position is relative to the `Rectangle` AND uses the `x` and `y` coordinates. Setting the `Item`'s `x` and `y` directly to `-50` will solve that (Line 17, 18).

However that Item is completly redundant and reduced performance. You can change the size and position of the `MouseArea` directly to reduce the overhead. You can also do it by anchoring with negative margins. Something along the lines of:

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 15; height: 65
    property int oldY: y
    property bool yUwards: false
    property bool yDwards: false
    color: 'red'

    onYChanged: {
        if(y > oldY)  yDwards = true
        else if (y < oldY)  yUwards = true
        oldY = y
    }


    MouseArea {

        anchors.fill: parent  // I anchor directly to the Rectangle
        anchors.margins: -50  // and extend the area by setting negative margins
                              // You can also modify each margin (top, left, ...) seperatly

        drag.target: root
        focus: true
        hoverEnabled: true
        pressAndHoldInterval: 0
        drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
        drag.minimumY: table.y
        drag.maximumY: table.height - height - 10
        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: 'transparent'
            border.color: 'black'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `anchors.margins` was exactly the great solution! :) Thanks.

Comment: One other question please: the program is just like a table tennis game. The problem is that when playing the game on the *Desktop* kit (Windows), moving/dragging the rackets **doesn't affect** the speed of ball's movement but when run on an Android device, moving/dragging the rackets **affects** the speed of ball's movement; It reduces the ball's speed. Is there any solution to solve this too, please?

Comment: I can't solve your second question, for various reasons: 1. I don't have an android device to my avail to test it. 2. I don't have your code to test it. Start a new question, and share a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Maybe then someone can find a solution to that. Most likely you have some performance problems and tied the movement to the frame rate.

Comment: Good suggestion, OK, I'll do that. Thanks.